# Bash shell: Appending a newline after each input in a *.txt file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to save a list of numbers from 1 to 10 in a text file in bash, each on it's own line.

This is the code I used:

```
echo "1" >> test.txt
echo >> test.txt
echo "2" >> test.txt
```

When I call my file with `cat test.txt`, it prints out the numbers exactly like it needs to:

=> OUTPUT:

```
1

2
```

etc...

But when I open the .txt file outside of bash, the information is saved as: `12345678910`

Comment: How are you opening it outside of bash?

Comment: Bash is putting the newlines there. It sounds like the problem is with what you're using to view the file, it's ignoring them.

Comment: classic notepad. I tried with sublime and it works. Thanks!

Comment: You tagged the question with `linux`, so why would you have "classic notepad"?

Comment: Are you creating it on Unix and reading it on Windows? They use different characters for newline, and Windows might not recognize the Unix format.

Comment: Bash on ubuntu on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what you want

```
for i in `seq 1 10`; do echo $i >> test.txt; done
```

But trust `cat` over "Windows Notepad" and switch to Notepad++, Atom, Sublime, etc.

Comment: When I run into newline problems, sometimes I dump it via `od -xc` or some such.